# Why is our FAQ now a Help Center?

Tags: discussion

It looks like the FAQ has been replaced. In the title bar the "FAQ" link has been replaced with "help" and now directs to the [Help Center](https://photo.stackexchange.com/helpcenter). The [FAQ URL](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq) also redirects to this new help center.

I couldn't find any general info for Stack Exchange on why this change was implemented or when, I just happened to notice the change. Any additional info would be great.

Comment: Caught me by surprised, noticed it yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this explains the change and why it occurred:

[Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center)

Comment: I've always thought it confusing that this is a Q&A site and yet the FAQ has nothing to do with photography. With this change, FAQ is now http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent